# Data Structure: time cost, Big O notation

Tags: algorithm, big-o

> For large problems sizes, an algorithm with time cost `O(2^n)` is faster than an algorithm
>   that has time cost `O(N^2)`

Is this true or false?

What I think is that if C^n, C = constant and C > 1, then it will grow faster than
O(N^2).  Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For large problems sizes, an algorithm with time cost O(2<sup>n</sup>) is faster than an algorithm that has time cost O(n<sup>2</sup>).

**FALSE**, because 2<sup>n</sup> > n<sup>2</sup> for n > 4, and greater means slower.

> For C = constant and C > 1, C<sup>n</sup> grows faster than O(n<sup>2</sup>).

**TRUE**.

[Here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/share/clip?f=d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427ecetjcrvt7v) is a Wolfram|Alpha reference.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. So 2^N is greater than N^2  which means that N^2 is faster right??  I thought greater means faster..

Answer (score 2):

```
Yes, c^n grows faster than n^2, if c>1
if c=1 then c^n =1
if c<1 then c^n "decays"

Proof for c>1
let t(n) = (c^n)/(n^2)
now lim n-> infinity t(n) = (By L'Hospitals Rule) = lim (d/dn c^n) / lim(d/dn n^2)
= lim (d/dn c^n lg n) / lim(d/dn 2n)    
= lim (d/dn c^n lg n * lg n) / lim(d/dn 2)
-> infinity.
```

So by property described in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Related_asymptotic_notations, we say that n^2 grows slower.

Comment: d/dn c^n = c^n * log(c), so it should be c^n*lg^2(c)/2 -> inf

Comment: yeah I meant that and not c^n lg (n lg n)
Sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 1):

It's clearly false. You can convince yourself of this by trial and error of different values of `N`.

```
2^5 = 32 versus 5^2 = 25
2^6 = 64 versus 6^2 = 36
2^7 = 128 versus 7^2 = 49
```

As you can see, the exponential grows much faster than the quadratic.

To prove this claim, I would use induction with the base case of `N=5`. This step is left as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: Thank you very much!! So the greater value means time cost is much slower. Did I get it right??

Comment: Well you said the functions represent "time cost" so yes. A greater time cost would mean slower execution (by definition).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, c^n grows faster than n^2.

Comment: Put reference or give more details.